# How to display a NUMBER (not string) to have always 2 digits in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to find a way to `return` a `number` as 0.50 not 0.5

I found various solutions to display always 2 digits but all of them work only if the number ends in something other than 0 e.g. 0.05 works fine, but 0.20 will always be returned as 0.2

Again, I need `typeof(number)` to be `number` NOT `string`.

I am trying to solve this: [freecodecamp.org/challenges/exact-change](http://freecodecamp.org/challenges/exact-chang) and I need to return [["TWENTY", 60.00], ["TEN", 20.00], ["FIVE", 15.00], ["ONE", 1.00], ["QUARTER", 0.50], ["DIME", 0.20], ["PENNY", 0.04]] -- if I return for example ["QUARTER", "0.50"] it will not pass

Comment: It's impossible without converting to a string before displaying/outputting it. A number isn't stored internally as "0.5" or "0.50", and there is no reason to worry about trailing 0's except when you're outputting it as a string anyway.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: @Sasha number types don't store anything about how a number should be displayed, they only store information about the numeric value, and since 0.5 and 0.50 are the same numeric value, there is only one representative number. You can't control how it's displayed until you convert it to a string.

Comment: I edited my original question with more clarification about what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the context, I can see that they made it a bit confusing. I think you should not worry about the trailing `0`. I believe the test will pass if you return the correct output even though your output will have numbers like `0.5`. That should be fine.

Comment: I will try my hand at the challenge to make sure that it accepts that output.

Comment: @Paulpro you can paste this code: https://pastebin.com/9aDZCWuP in that validator, you'll see what you mean. (i know the code is not the most efficient one ever, i'm still learning)

Comment: @Sasha I solved it with different code. You can check it if you want: https://pastebin.com/Ud6dfkUy . The main thing to notice is just that the tester doesn't care that the output has numbers like `0.4` in it. The tests pass anyway.

Comment: @Sasha If I run your code I find that it fails for a separate reason. You are returning a 1 dimensional array, but the tester expects a 2D array as output (same format as the `cid` input array)`.

Comment: @Sasha As an example, when you return change, you return something like:

Comment: `["TWENTY",60,"TEN",20,"FIVE",15,"ONE",1,"QUARTER","0.50","DIME",0.2,"PENNY",0.04]`

Comment: @Sahsa But the test expects: `[["TWENTY",60],["TEN",20],["FIVE",15],["ONE",1],["QUARTER","0.50"],["DIME",0.2],["PENNY",0.04]]`

Comment: The `0.2` for the amount of DIME's is correct, but it needs to be a 2D array